# If $\{I_1,....I_r\}$ is a set of open intervals which are pairwise disjoint

Tags: real-analysis

If $\{I_1,....I_r\}$ is a set of open intervals which are pairwise disjoint and $I_i \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^s J_j, (i=1,2,,,r)$ where each $J_j$ is an open interval I need to show that $$\sum _{i=1}^r v(I_i)\leq\sum _{j=1}^s v(J_j)$$.

I was thinking that $$\bigcup_{j=1}^s J_j=\sum_iI+ \complement (\sum_iI) $$ therefore the volume of $$ \sum_ {j=1}^s v(J_j)\geq  \sum_ {j=1}^r v(I_i)$$

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What is $v$? The Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or simply$$\sum v(I_i)=v(\bigcup U_i)\le v(\bigcup J_i)\le\sum v(J_i)$$
where the first inequality follows from disjointness.

Comment: Typo: $U_i=I_i$.